# HTML Video Rotation, Size and Positioning

Tags: css, resize, position, html5-video, orientation

Hello :) I am attempting to learn some very basic HTML, and I am having problems getting a video to behave the way I want it to :( I wish that I could have 3 images and the video, displayed at the same size, next to each other on the same line, equidistant apart.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="flex-container2">

<img src="lolly_jar.jpg" 

style="width:200px;height:400px;padding-left:20px;">



<img src="lolly_jar_top_down.jpg" 

style="width:200px;height:400px;padding-left:20px;">



<img src="lolly_jar_with_measurement.jpg" 

style="width:200px;height:400px;padding-left:20px;">


<rotates>
<video style="width:75%;" autoplay loop muted  
    <source src="lolly_jar_movie_best.MOV" type = "video/MOV" > >

</rotates>
```

and my CSS looks like this

```
[![.flex-container2 {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;

padding-top:20px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;

}

/* I need to rotate the video or it plays horizontally because 
of the way I shot it on my phone */

rotates {
     display:block;
     -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
     -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
     transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</div>
```

I attached below what my current code ends up looking like. I really CANNOT figure out why the video is in a weird position, or why it seems to have a bunch of space around it...

Thank you everyone for your help and time
[image: 3 pictures display fine, video much higher and further right than should be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got the style sheet set up for your HTML document?
For example, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/downtownboxingglobal.css">`?

Why don't you try rigging a navbar to play them horizontally next to each other?
Here's the W3Schools tutorial on navigation bars. In particular you'll want to read the section on horizontal navbars.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

And here is their code for it with a handy in browser viewport.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_float

Comment: yes I have a link in the header <link rel="stylesheet" href="lolly_jar_style1.css">

Comment: In that case I'm sure some clever padding or re-diving could clear it up, but it may just be easier to use VLC or Windows Movie Maker to rotate the video and save over the old one.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right I am going to rotate it and save it again :)

Comment: yes I found an online site that rotated the video for me and now it works like I expected it to in the first place, so thank you! :)